# Multiple windows painting

Tags: c, winapi

How can i avoid that my windows framerates get stuck to the bottleneck window ?

- I have one window that run at 10 FPS when display alone.
- I have another window that run at 60 FPS when display alone.

My problem is i get 10 FPS by window when i display the two windows together.

I was expecting that the fast window will be faster than the slow window, but the two windows get the same slower FPS speed when painting at the same time.

I was expecting to get about 5 FPS for the slow and 30 FPS for the fast window.

Have tried with timeSetEvent() instead SetTimer(), and it only paint the slow window, when set with a tiny time.

Have tried a custom paint message with timeSetEvent(TIME_ONESHOT), that give me the same slow result as with WM_TIMER.

Have added off/on buttons to easy see what the FPS are doing without changing the code.

As i understand, the fast window is waiting for the slow window to finish his paint.
Very very thanks for your help...

Here the full code **main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define TIMER_WND0      0
#define TIMER_WND1      1

#define OFF_ON_WND0     0
#define OFF_ON_WND1     1

LRESULT CALLBACK procWndMain(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK procWnd0(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK procWnd1(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HINSTANCE hInst = NULL;
HWND hWndMain = NULL;
HWND hWnd0 = NULL;
HWND hWnd1 = NULL;

int offOnWnd0 = 1;
int offOnWnd1 = 1;

void uint2str(char *buf, unsigned int x) {
    sprintf(buf, "%u", x);
    }
double millitimeTick(void) {
    return GetTickCount()/1000.0;
    }
int randInt(int a, int b) {
    return rand()%(b-a) +a;
    }

void createWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInstance, WNDPROC wndProc, LPCSTR lpszClassName, int bg, unsigned int style) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = style;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = lpszClassName;
    if(bg) { wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH); }
    else{ wc.hbrBackground = NULL; }
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, lpszClassName, "Error RegisterClassEx", MB_OK);
        }
    }

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpszArg, int nCmdShow) {
    (void)hPrevInst;
    (void)lpszArg;
    MSG message = {0};
    hInst = hInstance;

    createWindowClass(hInstance, procWndMain, "procWndMain", 1, CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW);
    hWndMain = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT,
        "procWndMain",
        "multiWndPaint",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        (int)CW_USEDEFAULT, (int)CW_USEDEFAULT,
        950, 370,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );
    ShowWindow(hWndMain, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWndMain);

    while(GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
        }

    UnregisterClass("procWndMain", hInst);
    return (int)message.wParam;
    }

LRESULT CALLBACK procWndMain(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            createWindowClass(hInst, procWnd0, "procWnd0", 1, 0);
            hWnd0 = CreateWindowEx(
                0,
                "procWnd0",
                "",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DLGFRAME,
                20, 22,
                440, 300,
                hwnd,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL
                );
            ShowWindow(hWnd0, SW_SHOW);

            createWindowClass(hInst, procWnd1, "procWnd1", 1, 0);
            hWnd1 = CreateWindowEx(
                0,
                "procWnd1",
                "",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DLGFRAME,
                480, 22,
                440, 300,
                hwnd,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL
                );
            ShowWindow(hWnd1, SW_SHOW);

            HWND btnWnd0 = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Off/On Wnd0",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                20, 0, 104, 24,
                hwnd,
                (HMENU)OFF_ON_WND0,
                NULL, NULL
                );
            ShowWindow(btnWnd0, SW_SHOW);

            HWND btnWnd1 = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Off/On Wnd1",
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                480, 0, 104, 24,
                hwnd,
                (HMENU)OFF_ON_WND1,
                NULL, NULL
                );
            ShowWindow(btnWnd1, SW_SHOW);
            break;
            }

        case WM_COMMAND: {
            if(LOWORD(wParam) == OFF_ON_WND0) {
                if(offOnWnd0) {
                    KillTimer(hWnd0, TIMER_WND0);
                    offOnWnd0 = 0;
                    }
                else{
                    SetTimer(hWnd0, TIMER_WND0, 1, NULL);
                    offOnWnd0 = 1;
                    }
                }

            else if(LOWORD(wParam) == OFF_ON_WND1) {
                if(offOnWnd1) {
                    KillTimer(hWnd1, TIMER_WND1);
                    offOnWnd1 = 0;
                    }
                else{
                    SetTimer(hWnd1, TIMER_WND1, 1, NULL);
                    offOnWnd1 = 1;
                    }
                }
            break;
            }

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            KillTimer(hWnd0, TIMER_WND0);
            KillTimer(hWnd1, TIMER_WND1);
            UnregisterClass("procWnd0", hInst);
            UnregisterClass("procWnd1", hInst);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
            }

        default: {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }

void wndInfo(HDC *hdcMem, char *name, unsigned int frame, unsigned int frameRate, unsigned int frameMax) {
    char buf64[24];
    char textInfo[256];
    RECT rect = {0};

    strcpy(textInfo, name);
    strcat(textInfo, "\n");

    uint2str(buf64, frame);
    strcat(textInfo, "Frame : ");
    strcat(textInfo, buf64);

    uint2str(buf64, frameRate);
    strcat(textInfo, "\nFPS : ");
    strcat(textInfo, buf64);

    uint2str(buf64, frameMax);
    strcat(textInfo, "\nMax : ");
    strcat(textInfo, buf64);

    HBRUSH brush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    rect.right = 100;
    rect.bottom = 70;
    FillRect(*hdcMem, &rect, brush);

    rect.left = 4;
    rect.top = 2;
    rect.right = 100;
    rect.bottom = 70;
    SetTextColor(*hdcMem, RGB(0,0,255));
    DrawText(*hdcMem, textInfo, -1, &rect, DT_NOCLIP|DT_NOPREFIX);

    DeleteObject(brush);
    }

LRESULT CALLBACK procWnd0(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static double timestamp = 0;
    static unsigned int frame = 0;
    static unsigned int frameRate = 0;
    static unsigned int frameMax = 0;

    switch(msg) {
        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            RECT rect = {0};
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            HBITMAP bmpMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rect.right, rect.bottom);
            HBITMAP bmpMemOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, bmpMem);

            SetBkMode(hdcMem, TRANSPARENT);
            SetTextColor(hdcMem, RGB(255,255,255));

            HBRUSH brush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
            FillRect(hdcMem, &rect, brush);

            POINT point = {0};
            size_t i = 0;
            size_t len = 99999;
            while(i < len) {
                point.x = randInt(-rect.right*8, rect.right*8);
                point.y = randInt(-rect.bottom*8, rect.bottom*8);
                TextOut(hdcMem, point.x, point.y, "foobar", 6);
                i++;
                }

            frame++;
            double timestampCur = millitimeTick();
            if(timestampCur > timestamp+1.0) {
                timestamp = timestampCur;
                frameRate = frame;
                if(frame > frameMax) { frameMax = frame; }
                frame = 0;
                }

            wndInfo(&hdcMem, "Wnd0", frame, frameRate, frameMax);

            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            DeleteObject(brush);
            SelectObject(hdcMem, bmpMemOld);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem);
            DeleteObject(bmpMem);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
            }

        case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
            break;
            }

        case WM_TIMER: {
            if(wParam == TIMER_WND0) {
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
                }
            break;
            }

        case WM_CREATE: {
            SetTimer(hwnd, TIMER_WND0, 1, NULL);
            break;
            }

        default: {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }

LRESULT CALLBACK procWnd1(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static double timestamp = 0;
    static unsigned int frame = 0;
    static unsigned int frameRate = 0;
    static unsigned int frameMax = 0;

    switch(msg) {
        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            RECT rect = {0};
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            HBITMAP bmpMem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rect.right, rect.bottom);
            HBITMAP bmpMemOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, bmpMem);

            SetBkMode(hdcMem, TRANSPARENT);
            SetTextColor(hdcMem, RGB(255,255,255));

            HBRUSH brush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
            FillRect(hdcMem, &rect, brush);

            POINT point = {0};
            size_t i = 0;
            size_t len = 999;
            while(i < len) {
                point.x = randInt(-rect.right*8, rect.right*8);
                point.y = randInt(-rect.bottom*8, rect.bottom*8);
                TextOut(hdcMem, point.x, point.y, "foobar", 6);
                i++;
                }

            frame++;
            double timestampCur = millitimeTick();
            if(timestampCur > timestamp+1.0) {
                timestamp = timestampCur;
                frameRate = frame;
                if(frame > frameMax) { frameMax = frame; }
                frame = 0;
                }

            wndInfo(&hdcMem, "Wnd1", frame, frameRate, frameMax);

            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            DeleteObject(brush);
            SelectObject(hdcMem, bmpMemOld);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem);
            DeleteObject(bmpMem);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;
            }

        case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
            break;
            }

        case WM_TIMER: {
            if(wParam == TIMER_WND1) {
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
                }
            break;
            }

        case WM_CREATE: {
            SetTimer(hwnd, TIMER_WND1, 1, NULL);
            break;
            }

        default: {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What about pre-painting the slow window into a DIB so the actual paint is just a BitBlt?  "double-buffering" or (to prevent tearing) "triple-buffering."

Comment: This app is exactly to bench different painting render that normaly give the same result to the eye.
But i think i will need that later in my real app, to display many windows, without getting FPS lose like that.
Making a DIB does not change the result that the DIB FPS will become as slow as the DDB render window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 60 FPS window is taking approximately 16 ms *or less* to draw.  I say "*or less*" because, although you requested a timer interval of 1 ms, you're likely getting something on the order of 16 ms, since that's the default resolution of these timers.  So your fast window is limited by the timer resolution rather than its drawing speed.

Your 10 FPS window is taking approximately 100 ms to draw, and the "next" interval has already passed, so the timer should fire right away.  That fact that it's taking about 100 ms for the next frame suggests that the actual drawing time is very close to 100 ms.

When you show both windows at the same time, they're *not* painted in parallel.  The WM_TIMER messages are sent when your message loop calls GetMessage and DispatchMessage.  If your code is busy painting window one when window two's timer expires, then window two's WM_TIMER message is going to be delayed until window one is done and returns from its window procedure to the message loop.

So one of them gets painted, and then the other.  You're again limited by the total time of the two windows.  The fast window can't run faster than the slow window.

(There are other complications as well, but these are the dominant factors in your experiment.)

There's not really a good solution here.  It's notoriously difficult to use GDI from multiple threads in the same process.  If you could put one window in one process and the other in another, then you could visually see them run at their top rates, side-by-side.

Comment: Great explain! thanks you :) it sadly confirm what i was expecting...
Im going to try the threads experiment with _beginthread(), can you explain a little more the difficulty with GDI?

Comment: I would say "sadly confirm what i was suspecting", sorry for my poor english, i havent reread me enough...
Have found that the GDI difficulties are like for sharing/using/deleting objects between threads (that maybe need use of a "critical section"), that seem to me like the problem with variables between threads.
Okay, i will experiment that and only then, speak... :D very Thanks again for your analysis.

Comment: I haven't actually tried multithreading with GDI, but I believe everything in GDI (and some stuff in user) is "sticky" to the thread that created it.  I would start by creating the second thread and have each thread register its own window class, create its own window, and run its own message loop.  Shutdown and cleanup might be confusing, but if this is just for a test, that might not be important.